# Main loop with if statement not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```
def nChar(nc):
    grid = len(nc)
    chars = set()
    for line in nc:
        line = set(line)
        if len(line) != grid or len(chars) != grid:
            return False
    return True
```

*Whats wrong?*
when I open a file which looks like

```
ABC
BCA
CAB
```

It should be fine as it is a n x n square (gridValidation) and there are exactly n different characters (nChar - problem in code).

for gridValidation I am using

```
except ValueError: print("error")
```

and that works fine.

For nChar I am using:

```
if not nChar(latinsq):
    print ("File does not have n different characters.")
    break
else:
    continue
```

If I enter filename example: ABC it keeps repeating "Enter filename". It has to do with the def  nChar or the way I am using it in the main loop.

an example of one file without n x n:

```
ABC
BCA
CAB
D
```

example file which does not have n different characters.

```
ABD
BCA
CAB
```

^has 4 different characters, but its  3x3.

I hope someone can explain what I am doing wrong so I can learn what I am doing wrong and also fix the problem.

ty.

EDIT:
I read through my post and it doesn't make sense.

The problem is that when I execute the code and enter the filename, it keeps saying "Enter Filename".

Comment: Does it print anything else?  That is, are any of the error messages printed?

Comment: @zondo nope. It doesn't print anything else apart from "Enter File name:" over and over again. If I remove the "else: continue" it then runs the program.

Comment: @zondo but then the nChar isn't working :S

Comment: I would expect this code to crash with an IndentationError because `except FileNotFoundError` does not line up with its accompanying `try`. And the `print`s under that are misaligned from one another. Please verify that the code that appears here is exactly the same as the code you're running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you say `else: continue` with your `if not nChar(latinsq):` block.  If you get to that point, either the square is wrong and you break, or the square is right and you don't.  You should change the `if` block to use `continue`, and remove the `else` block all together.  Your second problem is that `nChar()` is not returning the right thing.  It is always checking if the number of unique characters in the *line* is more than the number of lines, but you don't see if the *total* number of characters is too many.  You can check it all like this:

```
def nChar(nc):
    grid = len(nc)
    chars = set()
    for line in nc:
        line = set(line)
        chars = chars.union(line)
        if len(line) != grid or len(chars) != grid:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: ok thanks that makes a lot more sense when you read the code you wrote. Also nice to learn about .union...Thanks zondo! p.s it works now. :)

Comment: what is the purpose of chars = set() ? Does it make an empty set? I included this in my code and if im honest I didn't really understand the if statement and it may sound weird but it felt like I was cheating myself :S.

Comment: When I say `line = set(line)`, I am removing all of the duplicates in `line`.  That way, when I check `len(line) != grid`, having `AAB` will not work.  It needs to have that many *unique* letters.  I say `chars = chars.union(line)` because if `line` has any letters that `chars` doesn't have, that will add those letters to `chars`.  If that makes `chars` too many letters, it won't pass the `if` test.  I start out with `chars = set()` so that when I add the first line to `chars`, we actually know which letters we are dealing with.  I'm not sure if that is clear, but I'm still around if it isn't.